# How many 6-digit numbers are there that have at most 2 different digits?

Tags: combinatorics

I did this by making cases.

**Case 1: Exactly 0 different digits**

This means there are exactly 6 same digits, which means the numbers are 111111,222222,...999999

**$\to$ 9 such numbers**

**Case 2: Exactly 1 different digit**

If there is 1 different digit, it implies that there are 5 same digits. An example of such a number would be 155555. But this number has two different digits. So a case with exactly 1 different digit does not exist.

**Case 3: Exactly 2 different digits**

The numbers, in raw arrangement, are of the form **abbbbbb**, **aabbbb** or **aaabbb**. Later we will arrange the numbers within each form to get all possible arrangements, such as **abbbbb $\to$ babbbb, bbabbb, bbbabb, bbbbab, bbbbbba**

**- Subcase 1: abbbbb**

There will be $\binom{10}{1}$ ways to select **a** and $\binom{9}{1}$ ways to select **b**. By stars-and-bars, we see that there are $\binom{6}{1}$ ways to arrange our number **abbbbb**.

But the catch is that there will be numbers counted that begin from 0. By linearity of expectation, if $n$ numbers begin from 0, then $n$ numbers begin from 1, $n$ numbers begin from 2 and so on. So the total number of numbers that do not begin with 0 are $9n$ which is equal to $\frac{9}{10}\cdot\binom{10}{1}\cdot\binom{9}{1}\cdot\binom{6}{1}=486$

**- Subcase 2: aabbbb**

Working like subcase 1, there will be $\binom{10}{1}$ ways to select **a** and $\binom{9}{1}$ ways to select **b**. By stars-and-bars, we see that here there will be $\binom{6}{2}$ to arrange **aabbbb**. And by linearity of expectation, we take only $\frac{9}{10}$ of the values.

Total values obtained from this case are $\frac{9}{10}\cdot\binom{10}{1}\cdot\binom{9}{1}\cdot\binom{6}{2}=1215$.

**- Subcase 3: aaabbb**

Everything is same as mentioned above, but the number of arrangements using stars-and-bars will change to $\binom{6}{3}$. So the total cases obtained will be $\frac{9}{10}\cdot\binom{10}{1}\cdot\binom{9}{1}\cdot\binom{6}{3}=1620$

So in the end, we will have $9+486+1215+1620=3330$ cases.

I know that I have answered my own question, but I would also like to verify it against others. Is there any error in my counting? Is this the correct solution, or are there overlapping numbers/numbers I might have missed? Please let me know in the comments.

Thank you!

**Edit**: In the last subcase, we are recounting several numbers, for example a number of the form **aaabbb** is recounted as **bbbaaa**, or **ababba** is recounted as **babaab**, for 2 different combinations of **a** and **b**. To eliminate these cases, we divide the entire case by **2**.

$\to$ **Subcase 3** yields $\frac{1620}{2}=810$ cases, and hence our final answer is $2520$.

Comment: In your final subcase, since you are choosing two numbers that will each appear three times, you should have $\frac{9}{10}\binom{10}{2}\binom{6}{3}$.  Your method counts this case twice.  For instance, you count the number $111222$ twice, once when you choose $1$ as your first number, choose $2$ as your second number, and place your first number in the first three positions, and once when you choose $2$ as your first number, $1$ as your second number, and place your first number in the last three positions.

Comment: Thanks! I got my mistake. I have edited my post to include my error, but does Stack Exchange work that way? Namely, if I get an error, do I post an edit on my question or do I just comment on it?

Comment: What you did is fine.  Had you discovered your error before receiving an answer, you could answer your own question.  If you corrected your attempt after reading a comment or an answer, you should credit the person who corrected your error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When all digits are same then there are $9$ ways.

---

**When two different digits are used and one of them is $0$**

Select any digit and fix it on the leftmost place. This can be done in $9$ ways. Then the next $5$ places can be filled with $0$ and the number selected. There are $32$ ways to arrange those five places but we will exclude one case in which the number has all digits same. So in total $31$ cases for each selected number or total $31×9$ cases.

---

**When two different digits are used and none of them is $0$**

Select any two digits. This can be done in $36$ ways. Now they can be arranged in those $6$ places in $2^6$ ways. But we exclude two cases where the number has no different digits. So the total number of ways is $36×(2^6-2)$

---

So in total there are $$2520$$ ways.

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You must have made an error since there are $2^6\cdot\binom{10}{9}=2880$ ways to have a 6 digit number using at most 2 different digits if we also allow numbers to start with 0 and this is less than $3321$.

I believe you made an error in the last subcase since you are double counting as that case is symmetric between $a$ and $b$. If you divide that subcase's result by $2$ then you should have the right answer as the rest of the calculations look correct to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I suppose you've got an error in your answer. Could you check it?

Comment: I should’ve said 3330 instead of 3321 since you I didn’t notice that the 9 numbers with all digits the same wasn’t included in the final answer (but nonetheless that final answer was too large). But otherwise your method was correct modulo dividing by two for the last sub case.